# Access JSON hash element nested in array

Tags: json, ruby

I am trying to reference the string with same key name but wanted the second key-value to be printed. Example:

```
text = '[{ "name": "car",  "status": "good" },
         { "name": "bus",  "status": "bad" },
         { "name": "taxi", "status": "soso" }]'
```

I want to get to the `name` of the second element.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'json'
text = '[{ "name" : "car", "status": "good"}, { "name" : "bus", "status": "bad"},{ "name" : "taxi", "status": "soso"}]' # Note change to single outer quotes
puts JSON.load(text)[1]["name"]
# => bus
```

Because `text` is technically an Array of Hashes, you want to get the index value [1] then looking at the Hash key ["name"]

Comment: In Ruby the convention has steered towards `load` and `dump` for things like JSON, YAML and other serializers like Marshal. `JSON.load` is the recommended name here.